# Remove title from custom post type edit screen

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I apply the `remove_post_type_support('email_template', 'title');` only for post edit screen?

The title should be available on create and not for edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WordPress, there is one global variable to check on which screen we are and it is `global $current_screen` but problem is it can not be used with `admin_init` action.

So alternatively we can use [load-(page)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page)) action to achieve it.

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'remove_post_type_edit_screen', 10 );
function remove_post_type_edit_screen() {
    global $typenow;

    if($typenow && $typenow === 'email_template'){
        remove_post_type_support( 'email_template', 'title' );
    }
}
```

You can try it and give it a go.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

**Edited**

Explanation : If you can notice on the URL bar of the browser, then you can see when you are adding new post then it is calling **post-new.php** and when you are editing at that time it is calling **post.php** with parameters.

So we can utilize it to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Awesome solution, working fine. Can you explain how it works only on edit screen?

Comment: Edited with explanation in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can we just disable title edit for custom post type instead of completely removing Title support ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make small function in your `function.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'email_template_hide_title');
function email_template_hide_title() {
     remove_post_type_support('email_template', 'title');
}
```

I hope, It'll be help.

Comment: I have implemented the same, but it will remove title from create screen as well. I don't want to remove title in create screen.