# Remove title from specific custom post type edit screen

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to remove the custom post type title field from specific custom post type in WordPress
My Custom post type is: `post_type=dosage-details` So I remove this post type title field.

Comment: Please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562995/remove-title-from-custom-post-type-edit-screen

Comment: I want this in my specific custom post type but they write only post pages

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following code to your functions.php:

```
function remove_post_type_title() {

    remove_post_type_support( 'dosage-details', 'title' );

}

add_action( 'init', 'remove_post_type_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the post type inside the loop by using the [get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) So you can have something like:

```
//if the post type is not 'dosage-details'
if ( 'dosage-details' != get_post_type() ) {
    the_title();
}
```